# Seaborn relplot() doesn't load graph

Tags: python, seaborn, relplot

Hadn't messed with Seaborn in a while, so I was refreshing some basic concepts and came across this. When I load a basic plot using replot(), the graph doesn't load. It stops short from actually opening. However, if I use a scatterplot() instead, it loads just fine. Why? What am I missing?

```
penguins = sns.load_dataset('penguins')
sns.set(style='darkgrid')
sns.relplot(x='bill_length_mm',
            y='flipper_length_mm',data=penguins)
plt.show()
```

Using a scatterplot(), the graph loads without a problem.

```
sns.set(style='darkgrid')
sns.scatterplot(x='bill_length_mm',
            y='flipper_length_mm',data=penguins)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I have run it in my environment and the graph is displayed correctly. I would suggest that you update the version you are using or reinstall the software.

Comment: @r-beginners Which software do you mean? Seaborn itself? Python? I also am running Python 3.10. Last time I used Seaborn, I ran it on 3.8. Maybe that's the reason, but I doubt it.

Comment: I would suggest that if your Seaborn is not up to date, you should try upgrading it.

Comment: If you have `plt.show()`, then you have already imported matplotlib, right?

Comment: @r-beginners Yeah, it's the latest version. I'm dumfounded. Don't know what to think...

Comment: @r-beginners Yes, all the modules are there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what to tell you, it works fine for me. Do your other outputs match mine?

[image: example Image]

Comment: Yep, exact same thing. Crazy...

Comment: Are you using conda or pip to install?

Comment: Yeah, in fact, I've just installed conda, and needles to say, it worked. I still want to know why's going on. I tried it on my other computer, and same thing; I hit a wall. The graph flashes momentarily on the screen, but it fails to fully load. Even stranger that it doesn't work on my other computer, yet it works for you and the other gent that commented on this post.

Comment: I created a new env: `conda create -n deleteme python=3.10 matplotlib seaborn notebook` and then launched a notebook from that env, and it worked perfectly.